# Are "max_length" and "choices" in Model's class definition supposed to prevent from inserting invalid values into the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a situation where I have a model like:

```
class Box(models.Model):
    
  BOX_CHOICES = [('L','Large'),('M','Medium'),('S','Small')]
    
  size= models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=BOX_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

I thought that this would ensure that I couldn't add a string like "Humongous" into the size field. And yet, I was able to accomplish just that using the get_or_create function to insert.
Could you please explain how come the max_length and choices did not restrict that from inserting?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you run makemigrations after making these changes?

Comment: @Sumithran
 Yes, I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_or_create()` (like `create()`) doesn't call `full_clean()`, the validation function which checks things like choices, max_length, etc.  So you'll need to run it yourself:

```py
try:
    box = Box.objects.get(**your_get_values)
except Box.DoesNotExist:
    box = Box(**your_get_values, **any_other_values) 
    box.full_clean()
    box.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

The max_length and choices validators are called by full_clean, as explained in the [documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) You can call this method manually:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
try:
    box = Box.objects.create(size="L")
    box.full_clean()
    box.save()
except ValidationError:
    pass
```